# How to print <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

When I click the button it prints `<div>` content. But the next time it does not work.

```
var printContents = document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML;
var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
```

Comment: can you add your 'event' code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function printdiv(printpage) {
  var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
  var footstr = "</body>";
  var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML;
  var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
  document.body.innerHTML = headstr + newstr + footstr;
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>div print</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input name="b_print" type="button" class="ipt" onClick="printdiv('div_print');" value=" Print ">
  <div id="div_print">
    <h1 style="Color:Red">The Div content which you want to print</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Something like this :--
Hope it will help you ..
https://forums.asp.net/t/1261525.aspx

Comment: I have not printer LOL!